# Compare SDN Mininet results to traditional network results

Tags: testing, networking, ns2, sdn, mininet

My topic is: Comparative performance analysis of SDN-based network and traditional network. So I decided to use mininet and already know how to perform some tests. However, I am wondering what tests would be better to choose (throughput, jitter, packet delivery ratio, latency, end packet delay, etc.) and **how/where actually I can do tests for traditional network? NS2?** What would be you suggestions? Maybe any useful links/tutorials?

Many thanks,

Comment: ? Some hints : Google https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=ns2+SDN-based+network 

Example code
 
1. http://ns2simulator.com/software-defined-networking-in-ns2/ 

2. http://home.cse.ust.hk/~amas/files/HKUST-CS16-02-SDNGCC.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You should first use the same simulator to simulate the both networks types. The traditional and SDN are almost the same. The only difference is the management view and the flexibility.

You need first to:

1. set your goals from the study. Why you are performing this study? Has someone did this before? google scholar and check.
2. If some people have done this then think in some metrics or objectives they were missing and then start to think how to highlight them.
3. A good start for SDN research is always this paper (http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6994333/).
4. Try to comment to let us know more in case this is not sufficient. I'm doing my PhD in SDN so I would like to help and exchange knowledge.